# S3 Upload with Amazon IOS Sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know its a known issue but has anyone found a way to "fix" the connection failure on iPhone in 3G of "relativly" large files ?

My application depends highly on S3 for upload and keeps failing uploads of files larger then 200KB

Comment: Glad you have got the issue fixed. If you get into other issues, may be i can help you. I have uploaded files upto 2GB size flawlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out some time ago but forgot to update the reply, actually what was happening was that i was using an HTTP connection and it seems that if uploading Media files there are some Operators that have online "Conversors" dont know how to call them that take for instance your JPEG and "optimize" that jpg for mobile devices (this also applies to other media types), and since that modified the file that wont match S3 Header with the file "HASH", the way i worked around the problem was to use an HTTPS connection which prevents those intermediary servers to modify my upload

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what's causing the failure.

An easy, albeit imperfect solution is to increase the timeout on your AmazonS3Client:

```
s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:S3_SECRET_KEY];
s3.timeout = 240;
```